# bower - when should I use dependency vs. devDependency when writing a library?

Tags: bower

Seems weird to me that I get dependency conflict on things I shouldn't. Lets take angular and angular-datepicker for example.

When I add a dependency on angular-datepicker, I get a conflict for another angular version.

In npm the resolved dependencies are used in runtime. so if angular-datepicker was to run in npm, it would have used its own version of angular at runtime. which makes sense.

However this is not the case in bower, since the runtime versions are shared, and angular-datepicker's angular version is only used for development, not for runtime.

the more libraries I add, the harder it gets to "satisfy" all.

seems to me like all the libraries should declare angular as a devDependency instead of a dependency - as they expect the project using them to be dependent on angular directly rather than use their angular.

but then, when should I use dependencies?

Can someone clarify this issue to me please.

Comment: One question is how are you getting a conflict with a dependency in your angular-datepicker `bower.json`? That doesn't make sense because why would a `bower install` on your app even look at the `bower.json` inside one of your app's dependencies? All the `angular-datepicker` packages I can see do have a dependency on Angular...but they don't get called by `bower install` at your app's level.

Comment: @YPCrumble Did you never get a conflict doing bower install? perhaps my example is incorrect (even though I checked). the question is not specific for a library, but a general wondering of what is the purpose of such dependency check, since it is not really used in runtime

Answer (score 1):

You should use `devDependency` for parts of the app that you might need as a developer to build/test/compile/serve the app. Things like your test suite or your gulp/other task runners.

You should use `dependency` for anything that the client needs to run the compiled app. In your case, both Angular and Angular datepicker are dependencies.

One main difference is that if you run bower install -p (for production) you will only install into your bower_components directory and ignore devDependencies.

It sounds like what is happening is that your app is running one version of Angular and your Angular-datepicker plugin is running a different version of Angular. A good solution is to either update everything to the latest Angular version, or if that's not possible choose the version of your angular-datepicker plugin that is compatible with the version of Angular you're running.

Comment: but, if I am a library and there's a project using me,  I don't really expect the project to use "my" angular dependency. they most likely have their own. so what's my dependency's purpose?

Comment: @guymograbi in that case I think it's more for allowing developers and third party packages to understand exactly what dependencies the library has at runtime. The main difference I see between Bower and NPM is that bower doesn't recursively install dependencies, so you're right, in this case the dependencies just get ignored.

Comment: so you're suggesting it is just for documentation? I still don't see a scenario where "dependencies" should be used in a reusable library. As far as I understand it right now, reusable libraries should always use devDependencies and whoever is using them should be aware of their dependencies (from docs or something) and bring them along. Just like with CSS. Is there a way to tell bower to ignore them?